# R: How to write a function to do summation of a particular column values and report the row numbers when it meet certain criteria?

Tags: r, function, loops, if-statement, datatable

I am new to `R` and specially programming `function`.So, I would highly appreciate if you  please try to help to understand the concepts.

I'd like to know how I can write a `function` to do the following acts:

1- `add` the values of certain `variable`(column) `line by line (row by row)` and 
2- then if the `sum` of the value would be greater than 100; `>100`
3- then, `stop` and report all of the rows *from begging till it meets the criteria* (total sum <100) to stop?

As an example :

```
DT <- data.table(ID = c(1:21),Var1 = LETTERS[1:21], Var2 = seq(9, 19, .5))
> DT
    ID Var1 Var2
 1:  1    A  9.0
 2:  2    B  9.5
 3:  3    C 10.0
 4:  4    D 10.5
 5:  5    E 11.0
 6:  6    F 11.5
 7:  7    G 12.0
 8:  8    H 12.5
 9:  9    I 13.0
10: 10    J 13.5
11: 11    K 14.0
12: 12    L 14.5
13: 13    M 15.0
14: 14    N 15.5
15: 15    O 16.0
16: 16    P 16.5
17: 17    Q 17.0
18: 18    R 17.5
19: 19    S 18.0
20: 20    T 18.5
21: 21    U 19.0
    ID Var1 Var2
```

I'd like to `add` all of the value in `Var2` row by row until the `total sum` would be `> 100` then it stops and report all the rows from beginning till it meet this criteria.

I this case I mean, it add all of the values in `Var2` from `ID` `1:9 (9.0 +9.5+10+10.5+11+11.5+12+12.5+13)` which the total would be `99` and if add the next row (13.5) the values would be `112.5`.

therefore the expected output would be :

```
 ID Var1 Var2
 1:  1    A  9.0
 2:  2    B  9.5
 3:  3    C 10.0
 4:  4    D 10.5
 5:  5    E 11.0
 6:  6    F 11.5
 7:  7    G 12.0
 8:  8    H 12.5
 9:  9    I 13.0
```

I tried different things , but to me they were not useful at all, hence, I am not including them here .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it, it doesn't seem complicated. In `base R`,

```
DT[cumsum(DT$Var2) < 100, ]
```

As a function this can be done as folows. Note that I've separated the above in two lines of code, in order to make it more readable. In 6 months or so it will pay.

```
keep_below <- function(x, column = "Var2", threshold = 100){
    inx <- cumsum(x[[column]]) < threshold
    x[inx, ]
}

keep_below(DT)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. `cumsum` was the one I was not aware. May I also ask you please if it possible for you, help me to know , regardless of `cumsum`, how I can do this by writing a `function`

Comment: @Daniel Ok, you're right, I forgot that part of your question. I'll test it and then edit my answer. Just a moment.